# Is "do(es)" used to mean either single or plural subject?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if the following usage of "do(es)" properly or commonly used:

> If money doesn't concern you, what else do(es)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you read this somewhere, but do(es) shouldn't be used this way. "What" is singular and will always take the singular form of the verb: What else does?

Comment: are you saying "what" is never plural as a subject?

Comment: No, merely that the plural of _what_ turns out to be _what._ Cf. _What kind of thing is that? What kinds of things are those?_

Comment: @JohnLawler: In your examples, the subjects are "that" and "those" instead.

Comment: Also, in John and Peter's examples, *what* is a determiner, not a pronoun as it is in OP's question.

Comment: @Tim The point is that_what_ modifies (or is Chomsky-adjoined with, if you go to a different church) both singular and plural, and can stand for either; delete _kind(s) of thing(s)_ and the verb doesn't change.

Comment: I would also note that the '*else*' in the question is a bit dubious.  The use of '*else*' implies that there is at least one thing that bothers you and we are looking for another thing, but the question only talks about money. So it ought to be phrased:  "*If money doesn't bother you, what does?*" (without the *else*) because maybe the answer is, "Nothing."

Answer (score 3):

The default assumption for *what* is that it is singular. The main exception would be in an echo/confirmation question (e.g., A: *The sloders are green.* B:*What are green?*). Normally, the phrase in the original question would be *If money doesn't concern you, what else does?*